# How to compress a large number of files (resulting in high volumes) using cPanel File Manager

Tags: compression, cpanel

I often find that the compression operation times out (without any notification message) when we try to compress large volumes of files in cPanel File Manager. I think it is due to some timeouts. I checked for the solution, but didn't find it. Probably I am missing something that's too obvious.

Does anyone know how to accomplish this?

I know this can be done using SSH, but is there a way to do this in cPanel File Manager?

Answer (score 0):

Some considerations...

File sizes are often restricted (eg.:max4GB). Have you tried to identify the filesize treshold?

There are ways to split files and compress them individually. Is splitting large files an option for you?

Maybe the resulting compressed file is too large. With programs like 7zip you can split a compressed file into volumes.

PS: it is not always true the problem lies with cpanel.

Comment: 1. The resulting file sizes vary each time. So I think it may be time limit
2. Can we split and compress using Cpanel File Manager? What I am expecting is cpanel FileManager solution.